# Rails global function available to all objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to make a function `current_order_week` that would be available globally throughout my app and could be called similarly to something like `current_user`.  I don't want to have to `include` it in a specific model / controller, I just want it available everywhere.

I've modified my `/lib` folder to include a `lib_extensions.rb` file and added to that file:

```
class Object
    def current_order_week
    end
end
```

I've modified my `application.rb` to include:

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

But when I attempt to call `current_order_week` from the console or from a test, I still see:

> `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'current_order_week'
>   for main:Object`

**What else do I need to do?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add this function in the `application_helper.rb` file. All controllers extend from `ApplicationController` and `ApplicationController` includes the `ApplicationHelper`.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def current_order_week
  end
end
```

This will be available to use in views and controllers

Answer (score 0):

Monkey-patching core classes like `Object` is usually not a good idea, this may interfere with some gems etc. and in general can lead to painful debugging in the future.

If you absolutely want to do this - autoloading will not pick up `Object` from lib, because it is already defined. Create an initializer in `config/initializers`, then it will be loaded, but it will not reload on code changes.

But better way is including such code in `ApplicationHelper`, `ApplicationRecord` and `ApplicationController`

Answer (score 0):

`autoload_paths` and `eager_load_paths` don't include modules, they only `require` files in which modules are defined. To use `current_order_week` you need to specify the name of the module:

```
module Foo
  def current_order_week
    .
    .
    .
  end
end

Foo.current_order_week()
```

In order to use `current_order_week` without  prepending the name of the module to it, you need to include `Foo` inside your controllers and models:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Foo

  def some_action
    current_order_week()
  end
end

class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Foo
end
```